# PHP Header Location

Tags: php, header

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP header() redirect with POST variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281900/php-header-redirect-with-post-variables)

I'm writing a script where form data is being submitted to another script. I want the second script to perform some error-checking on the submitted `$_POST` data, and if everything is okay, process the data. If the data has errors, I'm using `header('Location: http://www.example.com/script.php');` to return the visitor back to the form page.

The issue I'm having is that I want the form to be sticky - fields with correct data maintain the values the user put in them. Obviously, to get those values, I need access to the `$_POST` array. However, this seems to be destroyed when the `header()` call forwards the visitor back to the form.

Is there any way to use the header Location stuff to redirect the visitor to another page, while still preserving the `$_POST` data?

Now I'm using like this : `header('Location: http://www.example.com/add.php?id='.$id.'&name='.$name.'&code='.$code.'&desc='.$description.'');` and accessing as `$_GET`.

For the same can I use and kind of POST in `header('location: xxx')`??

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: You can [manually set `$_POST`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418044/setting-post-variable-without-using-form) again before redirecting.

Comment: why don't you set session variable to store the post data ? ?

Comment: @Havelock I don't even know where to begin to describe that that whole threat is terribly wrong. ;-(

Answer (score 15):

the best way to achieve this 'sticky form' is to use a session.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION = $_POST;
//do error checking here
//if all is valid
session_write_close();
header('Location: *where you want your form to go*');
die;
?>
```

and on the redirect page you can use them like so:

```
<?php
session_start();
//use $_SESSION like you would the post data
?>
```

Comment: NOTE: That will only work if both pages are in the same server.

Answer (score 3):

You could store the `$_POST` data in a session:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['submitted_data'] = $_POST;
```

And then load the values into the inputs by loading them from the `$_SESSION['submitted_data']` variable, just remember to have `session_start()` at the top of your error page too.

Answer (score 0):

Use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) for that. In the form page:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
    // we only start session if there is a session running
    session_id() || session_start();
}

if (empty($_POST) && !empty($_SESSION['POST'])) {
    // make sure you're not overwriting
    $_POST = $_SESSION['POST'];
}
// and so on just like you have $_POST filled
```

In a script that receives $_POST data:

```
<?php
// after you're done with checking and stuff
session_id() || session_start();
$_SESSION['POST'] = $_POST;
header('Location: /script.php');
```

Both scripts should be on the save domain for sessions to work. If you're using relative URI in the *Location* header, then everything should work fine.