# PHP adding backslashes to POST data

Tags: php

I have a form that submits to a database. But before it enters the database the submitted data is output on the screen. Currently, if I have "Mike's" submitted, it outputs "Mike\'s".

I have tried the below code to see if it is [Magic Quotes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php), but this has not helped.

```
if ((function_exists("get_magic_quotes_gpc") && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ||
    ini_get('magic_quotes_sybase')
   ) {

    foreach($_GET as $k => $v)
        $_GET[$k] = stripslashes($v);
    foreach($_POST as $k => $v)
        $_POST[$k] = stripslashes($v);
    foreach($_COOKIE as $k => $v)
        $_COOKIE[$k] = stripslashes($v);
}
```

What should I look for?

Comment: Use `phpinfo()` to see if magic quotes is turned on just to definitely rule it out.

Comment: Are you using sybase?

Comment: It might help to show the code that's outputting the data.

Comment: I'm running version 5.4 so I don't think there is even magic quotes within it

Comment: Does the data in the database have the character escapes in it?

Comment: Related: *[With “magic quotes” disabled, why does PHP/WordPress continue to auto-escape my POST data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949768)*

Answer (score 0):

Note: To sanitize the string

```
<?php

    $mike = "Mike's";

    echo filter_var($mike, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

?>
```

Comment: The suspense! What is it supposed to achieve (in that example)? Is the string changed in any way? If it is changed, what is it changed to?

Answer (score 0):

There's a possibility it's in the code you're using to output to the screen.

If you were, for instance, using `var_export()`, one would expect to see character escapes on apostrophes.

Answer (score 0):

Despite looking like a constant, editing $_POST [should work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3418136/819417). Then again, your code didn't work for me, either.

This works:

```
function getReq($key){
    return isset($_REQUEST[$key]) ? stripslashes($_REQUEST[$key]) : "";
}
```

I haven't found why PHP (5.3.0 on WAMPSERVER 2.0 in my case) seems to magically change POST data while `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` returns 0, and frankly don't care to waste more time on its dirty innards.

Answer (score 0):

It seems silly to answer after all these years but I see your post is active so i'll try.

First try this function `stripslashes()`. Doc: (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

Should this not work.

Do you display the data directly from the $_POST variable or retrieve it from the DB? 
It might be saved as is in the DB and that would mean a UTF8 convert issue.

I kept my answer short and don't wish to add more unncessary info unless you need it.