# POST parameters passed via url empty php

Tags: php, post

This seems like a very trivial question, but I'm new to php, so please bear with me.

This is the test php script I wrote:

```
<?php
$str = $_POST['str'];
echo('string entered: '.$str);
```

I post a request by typing this into the url:

```
myurl.com/test.php?str=Hello
```

Now, the response I'm getting is:

```
string entered:
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters in URL are `GET`, so you need to access them like

```
$param = $_GET['str'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're submitting a `GET` request. To access the parameter, use `$_GET['str']`

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the variable as a **GET parameter**, rather than **POST**. If you want to access the variable this way, you will need to try this:

```
<?php
$str = $_GET['str'];
echo ('string entered: '.$str);
```

Comment: How would I pass the variable as post parameter?

Comment: You will need to pass it with an HTML form, or you can set the value of an existing POST value just like any other array, which is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418044/setting-post-variable-without-using-form.

Comment: Alright and I can't do that through the url directly, can I?

Comment: Correct. POST is designed to be hidden from the browser, so if you're setting or modifying a value in the parameter list in the URL, you are modifying a GET variable.